# Updating properties in a class that contains an Enum

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-apicontroller, business-layer

You can see my PermissionUpdateDTO class below. My 'PermissionUpdateVM' class also has the same properties as these classes. PermissionStatus' and 'PermissionType' in this class are enums.

```
public class PermissionUpdateDTO
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int TotalLeaveDuration { get; set; }
     public DateTime StartDateOfLeave { get; set; }
     public DateTime EndDateOfLeave { get; set; }

     public DateTime RequestDateOfLeave = DateTime.Now;
     public DateTime DateOfLeaveApproval { get; set; }

     public PermissionStatus Status { get; set; }
     public PermissionType Type { get; set; }
 }
```

The Update method I have written in my PermissionService class, which inherits from my IPermissionService class to update these properties, is as follows:

```
  public ResultService<PermissionUpdateDTO> UpdateAsync(PermissionUpdateVM permissionUpdateVM)
        {
            ResultService<PermissionUpdateDTO> result = new ResultService<PermissionUpdateDTO>();

            Permission existingPermission =  _permissionRepo.GetFirstOrDefault(filter: x => x.Id == permissionUpdateVM.Id);

            if(existingPermission == null)
            {
                result.AddError(ErrorType.NotFound, "Kullanıcı Bulunamadı");
                return result;
            }

            existingPermission.TotalLeaveDuration = permissionUpdateVM.TotalLeaveDuration;
            existingPermission.StartDateOfLeave = permissionUpdateVM.StartDateOfLeave;
            existingPermission.EndDateOfLeave = permissionUpdateVM.EndDateOfLeave;
            existingPermission.RequestDateOfLeave= permissionUpdateVM.RequestDateOfLeave;
            existingPermission.DateOfLeaveApproval = permissionUpdateVM.DateOfLeaveApproval;

      
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(PermissionStatus), permissionUpdateVM.Status))
            {
                existingPermission.Status = (PermissionStatus)permissionUpdateVM.Status;
            }
            else
            {
                result.AddError(ErrorType.InvalidData, "Geçersiz PermissionStatus değeri");
                return result;
            }


            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(PermissionType), permissionUpdateVM.Type))
            {
                existingPermission.Type = (PermissionType)permissionUpdateVM.Type;
            }
            else
            {
                result.AddError(ErrorType.InvalidData, "Geçersiz PermissionType değeri");
                return result;
            }

            _permissionRepo.Update(existingPermission);

            return result;

        }
```

The 'Status' part in 'existingPermission.Status = (PermissionStatus)permissionUpdateVM.Status;' and the 'Type' part in 'existingPermission.Type = (PermissionType)permissionUpdateVM.Type;' are giving the error 'Permission' does not contain a definition for 'Type' and no accessible extension method... How can I fix this?

I also want to mention that I attempted to make the method Task-based. However, when I converted the method to Task, I encountered an error in the 'return result;' part. That's why I did it this way.

Comment: What is in your Permission entity? The error is pretty self explanatory in that it's saying the permission entity doesn't have a Status or Type property exposed. Does the entity use a enum for these values or a navigation property to another entity that uses an enum or int etc. for the PK?  Typically where I use an Enum for known values that have business logic meaning I would define entity and any VM/DTO to use the same common Enum definition. There is no need to declare multiple enums then try casting between them.

Comment: After your response, I revisited my Permission class and realized that I had specified the enums under the class, but I had forgotten to add the Enum itself as a property to the Permission class. Thank you for your answer.